# Segmentation fault using SCALAPACK in Fortran? No backtrace?

Tags: fortran, lapack, scalapack

I'm trying to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a Hermitian matrix using SCALAPACK and MPI in Fortran. For bug-squashing, I made this program as simple as possible, but am still getting a segmentation fault. Per the answers given to people with similar questions, I've tried changing all of my integers to integer*8, and all of my reals to real*8 or real*16, but I still get this issue. Most interestingly, I don't even get a backtrace for the segmentation fault: the program hangs up when trying to give me a backtrace and has to be aborted manually.

Also, please forgive my lack of knowledge -- I'm not familiar with most program-y things but I've done my best. Here is my code:

```
    PROGRAM easydiag
    IMPLICIT NONE 
  INCLUDE 'mpif.h'
  EXTERNAL BLACS_EXIT, BLACS_GET, BLACS_GRIDEXIT, BLACS_GRIDINFO
  EXTERNAL BLACS_GRIDINIT, BLACS_PINFO,BLACS_SETUP, DESCINIT 
  INTEGER,EXTERNAL::NUMROC,ICEIL
  REAL*8,EXTERNAL::PDLAMCH

  INTEGER,PARAMETER::XNDIM=4 ! MATRIX WILL BE XNDIM BY XNDIM
  INTEGER,PARAMETER::EXPND=XNDIM
  INTEGER,PARAMETER::NPROCS=1

  INTEGER COMM,MYID,ROOT,NUMPROCS,IERR,STATUS(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
  INTEGER NUM_DIM
  INTEGER NPROW,NPCOL
  INTEGER CONTEXT, MYROW, MYCOL

  COMPLEX*16,ALLOCATABLE::HH(:,:),ZZ(:,:),MATTODIAG(:,:)
  REAL*8:: EIG(2*XNDIM) ! EIGENVALUES
  CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
  CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,myid,ierr)
  CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,numprocs,ierr)
  ROOT=0

  NPROW=INT(SQRT(REAL(NPROCS)))
  NPCOL=NPROCS/NPROW   
  NUM_DIM=2*EXPND/NPROW

  CALL SL_init(CONTEXT,NPROW,NPCOL)
  CALL BLACS_GRIDINFO( CONTEXT, NPROW, NPCOL, MYROW, MYCOL )

  ALLOCATE(MATTODIAG(XNDIM,XNDIM),HH(NUM_DIM,NUM_DIM),ZZ(NUM_DIM,NUM_DIM))
  MATTODIAG=0.D0

  CALL MAKEHERMMAT(XNDIM,MATTODIAG)

  CALL MPIDIAGH(EXPND,MATTODIAG,ZZ,MYROW,MYCOL,NPROW,NPCOL,NUM_DIM,CONTEXT,EIG)


  DEALLOCATE(MATTODIAG,HH,ZZ)




   CALL MPI_FINALIZE(IERR)


END

!****************************************************
SUBROUTINE MAKEHERMMAT(XNDIM,MATTODIAG)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER:: XNDIM, I, J, COUNTER
  COMPLEX*16:: MATTODIAG(XNDIM,XNDIM)
  REAL*8:: RAND

  COUNTER = 1
  DO J=1,XNDIM
    DO I=J,XNDIM
        MATTODIAG(I,J)=COUNTER
        COUNTER=COUNTER+1
    END DO
  END DO




END
!****************************************************
SUBROUTINE MPIDIAGH(EXPND,A,Z,MYROW,MYCOL,NPROW,NPCOL,NUM_DIM,CONTEXT,W)
    IMPLICIT NONE
  EXTERNAL DESCINIT 
  REAL*8,EXTERNAL::PDLAMCH

  INTEGER EXPND,NUM_DIM
  INTEGER CONTEXT
  INTEGER MYCOL,MYROW,NPROW,NPCOL
  COMPLEX*16 A(NUM_DIM,NUM_DIM), Z(NUM_DIM,NUM_DIM)
  REAL*8 W(2*EXPND)

  INTEGER N
  CHARACTER JOBZ, RANGE, UPLO
  INTEGER IL,IU,IA,JA,IZ,JZ
  INTEGER LIWORK,LRWORK,LWORK
  INTEGER M, NZ, INFO

  REAL*8  ABSTOL, ORFAC, VL, VU

  INTEGER DESCA(50), DESCZ(50)
  INTEGER IFAIL(2*EXPND), ICLUSTR(2*NPROW*NPCOL)
  REAL*8 GAP(NPROW*NPCOL)
  INTEGER,ALLOCATABLE:: IWORK(:)
  REAL*8,ALLOCATABLE :: RWORK(:)
  COMPLEX*16,ALLOCATABLE::WORK(:)

  N=2*EXPND
  JOBZ='V'
  RANGE='I'
  UPLO='U' ! This should be U rather than L
  VL=0.d0
  VU=0.d0
  IL=1  ! EXPND/2+1
  IU=2*EXPND  !  EXPND+(EXPND/2)   ! HERE IS FOR THE CUTTING OFF OF THE STATE
  M=IU-IL+1
  ORFAC=-1.D0
  IA=1
  JA=1
  IZ=1
  JZ=1


  ABSTOL=PDLAMCH( CONTEXT, 'U')
  CALL DESCINIT( DESCA, N, N, NUM_DIM, NUM_DIM, 0, 0, CONTEXT, NUM_DIM, INFO )
  CALL DESCINIT( DESCZ, N, N, NUM_DIM, NUM_DIM, 0, 0, CONTEXT, NUM_DIM, INFO )



  LWORK = -1
  LRWORK = -1
  LIWORK = -1
  ALLOCATE(WORK(LWORK))
  ALLOCATE(RWORK(LRWORK))
  ALLOCATE(IWORK(LIWORK))


  CALL PZHEEVX( JOBZ, RANGE, UPLO, N, A, IA, JA, DESCA, VL, &
                VU, IL, IU, ABSTOL, M, NZ, W, ORFAC, Z, IZ, &
                JZ, DESCZ, WORK, LWORK, RWORK, LRWORK, IWORK, &
                LIWORK, IFAIL, ICLUSTR, GAP, INFO )

  LWORK = INT(ABS(WORK(1)))
  LRWORK = INT(ABS(RWORK(1)))
  LIWORK =INT (ABS(IWORK(1)))

  DEALLOCATE(WORK)
  DEALLOCATE(RWORK)
  DEALLOCATE(IWORK)

  ALLOCATE(WORK(LWORK))
  ALLOCATE(RWORK(LRWORK))
  ALLOCATE(IWORK(LIWORK))


         PRINT*, LWORK, LRWORK, LIWORK

  CALL PZHEEVX( JOBZ, RANGE, UPLO, N, A, IA, JA, DESCA, VL, &
                VU, IL, IU, ABSTOL, M, NZ, W, ORFAC, Z, IZ, &
                JZ, DESCZ, WORK, LWORK, RWORK, LRWORK, IWORK, &
                LIWORK, IFAIL, ICLUSTR, GAP, INFO )





  RETURN
END
```

The problem is with the second PZHEEVX function. I'm fairly certain that I'm using it correctly since this code is a simpler version of another more complicated code that works fine. For this purpose, I'm only using one processor.

Help!

Comment: Come to think of it, it's weird that you get a segfault, but the program seems to hang at the same time. Are you sure it's not just the parallel environment playing tricks on you?

Comment: And if you get to fix the segfault, won't `PZHEEVX` be sad that the input matrix is non-Hermitian? At least I don't see how your example `MAKEHERMMAT` will create a (real) symmetric matrix.

Comment: Any updates on this problem?:)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://www.mathkeisan.com/usersguide/man/pzheevx.html)
setting LWORK = -1 seems to request the PZHEEVX routine to return the necessary size of all the work arrays, for example,

> If LWORK = -1, then LWORK is global input and a workspace query
>                  is  assumed;  the  routine only calculates the optimal size for
>                  all work arrays. Each of these values is returned in the  first
>                  entry  of the corresponding work array, and no error message is
>                  issued by PXERBLA.

Similar explanations can be found for LRWORK = -1. As for IWORK,

> IWORK   (local workspace) INTEGER array
>                  On return, IWORK(1) contains the amount  of  integer  workspace
>                  required.

but in your program the work arrays are allocated as

```
LWORK = -1
LRWORK = -1
LIWORK = -1
ALLOCATE(WORK(LWORK))
ALLOCATE(RWORK(LRWORK))
ALLOCATE(IWORK(LIWORK))
```

and after the first call of PZHEEVX, the sizes of the work arrays are obtained as

```
LWORK = INT(ABS(WORK(1)))
LRWORK = INT(ABS(RWORK(1)))
LIWORK =INT (ABS(IWORK(1)))
```

which looks inconsistent (-1 vs 1). So it will be better to modify the allocation as (*)

```
allocate( WORK(1), RWORK(1), IWORK(1) )
```

An example in [this page](http://www.trentu.ca/academic/physics/batkinson/scalapack_docs/node15.html) also seems to allocate the work arrays this way. Another point of concern is that INT() is used in several places (for example, `NPROW=INT(SQRT(REAL(NPROCS)))`, but I guess it might be better to use NINT() to avoid the effect of round-off errors.

(*) More precisely, allocation of an array with -1 is not valid because the size of an allocated array becomes 0 (thanks to @francescalus). You can verify this by printing size(a) or a(:). To prevent this kind of error, it is very useful to attach compiler options like -fcheck=all (for gfortran) or -check (for ifort).

Comment: The original code allocates work(:) etc with negative scalars like allocate( work( -1 ) ). Although gfortran accepts this, I am not sure whether this is okay for other compilers...

Comment: `allocate(a(-1))` has the defined effect of allocating a zero-sized array.

Comment: @francescalus Because I had never allocated arrays with -1, I tested this with a simple program. Then both gfortran and ifort did not make a "beep" upon allocation with -1, and just segfaulted at run-time (when no bounds-check option was given). Even worse, gfortran prints the value of a(-1) correctly before segfault. I think the compiler should stop the program when arrays are allocated with -1... (not -1:-1).

Comment: Actually, it's simpler to use dedicated variables to catch the output of LAPACK functions in the workspace query mode. I'd use `complex*16 :: tmpwork; real*8 :: tmprwork; integer :: tmpiwork`, then put these variables into the subroutine call instead of `work`, `rwork` and `iwork`, respectively. Only afterwards would I allocate the corresponding arrays, with size `dble(tmpwork)`, `tmprwork` and `tmpiwork`, respectively, making use of an implicit conversion from double to integer.

Comment: A compiler has no choice on how it handles `allocate(a(-1))`: the rules of Fortran say the end result has to be allocated with a size of zero.  Of course, that's a valid thing to do and a problem comes about only when an element (which can't exist) is referenced.  As explained in the answer, with a workspace query such reference would be made.

Comment: To add to the comment of @francescalus: it might even make sense to have an array of size 0. Some functions, or even the f95 intrinsic `reshape`, need an array argument, but don't actually access it. I think I could only make `reshape` work with its full input syntax when I gave it an array of size 0.

Comment: @AndrasDeak You mean `integer :: tmpiwork(1)`, etc?  The dummy argument is an array.

Comment: @francescalus, I guess I do mean that, but I've been using it happily with the scalar syntax:) It might be non-standard; it works at least for `ifort 11.1` and `mkl 10.2.6`... And not `PZHEEVX` but `ZGETRI`, but this shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I'm interested in the cases where array of size 0 can be used advantageously in reshape(), so is it possible to write some examples in the comments (if it is very very small example)? If not, I could ask as a Question.

Comment: @roygvib, specifically, when you want to rearrange (permute) indices of an array, the number of elements doesn't change, so you don't need to set a padding value. But [the syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RESHAPE.html) goes like `RESHAPE(SOURCE, SHAPE[, PAD, ORDER])`, so in order to specify an `ORDER` you need a dummy `PAD`. You can in this case pass a `real*8 :: dummy(0)` as `PAD` when reshaping a double: `reshape(var(1:n1,1:n2,1:n3),(/n3,n1,n2/),dummy,(/3,1,2/))` will turn a `real*8 :: var(n1,n2,n3)` into `var2(n3,n1,n2)`. I wouldn't call it *advantageous* though.

Comment: I've made the appropriate changes but am still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Hmm.. I have never used reshape() that way, so I will make some experiments later and ask more if necessary.

Comment: @SamNorris Pls try attaching -fcheck=all (for gfortran) or -check (for ifort). There may be more inconsistency or unexpected size definition of arrays, I guess.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Use the argument keyword.  One could even write `reshape(order=(/3,1,2/), shape=(/n3,n1,n2/), source=var(1:n1,1:n2,1:n3))`, but `reshape(var(1:n1,1:n2,1:n3),(/n3,n1,n2/),order=(/3,1,2/))` is quite valid.

Comment: @francescalus, well, using language features properly is always easier;) Unfortunately, I was never taught proper usage of the various versions. Thanks for the tip:)

Comment: @roygvib Will try as soon as I figure out how :)

Comment: @SamNorris, they simply mean using compile switches, as in `gfortran -fcheck=all -o easydiag easydiag.f` or `ifort -C -o easydiag easydiag.f`. If you have a standard `makefile`, you probably have to add these to `FFLAGS`. They will turn on all kinds of checks, including runtime array bound checks (which we are interested in now). So compile, run, and see what's the message, if there's one. If the segfault comes about in a lapack function, you might not get additional info, then you have to scrutinize the input variables to the lapack calls.

Comment: Also, if it wasn't for MPI, I'd suggest running your program in `gdb` or any other debugger, that would let you catch the backtrace and explore the values and dimensions of variables. Although I've only used it to debug C++, and I don't know how well it gets along with MPI.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fishy piece of dimensioning in your code which can easily be responsible for the segfault. In your main program you set

```
EXPND=XNDIM=4
NUM_DIM=2*EXPND !NPROW==1 for a single-process test
ALLOCATE(MATTODIAG(XNDIM,XNDIM))   ! MATTODIAG(4,4)
```

Then you pass your `MATTODIAG`, the Hermitian matrix, to

```
CALL MPIDIAGH(EXPND,MATTODIAG,ZZ,MYROW,...)
```

which is in turn defined as

```
SUBROUTINE MPIDIAGH(EXPND,A,Z,MYROW,...)

COMPLEX*16 A(NUM_DIM,NUM_DIM)   ! A(8,8)
```

This is already an inconsistency, which can mess up the computations in that subroutine (even without having a segfault). Furthermore, the subroutine along with scalapack thinks that `A` is of size `(8,8)`, instead of `(4,4)` which you allocated in the main program, allowing the subroutine to overrun available memory.